# Pandas: Load CSV as 2D Matrix

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scipy

I'm just starting out with scipy/pandas so that might be absolutely easy but I am lost here.

I have a CSV file with 3 columns: User Artist Rating

Now I want to have a 2D matrix with the rows being users, the columns being artists and the ratings as content.

I tried `pandas.read_csv(file, index_col = [0,1])`, but then I get

```
               rating
user  artist         
amy   swift       4.0
      psy         3.0
      houston     4.0
ben   swift       5.0
      psy         2.0
clara psy         3.5
      houston     4.0
daisy swift       5.0
      houston     3.0
```

But now I cannot index rows and cols like data[:,:].
If I do `data.unstack()` the output is a 2D matrix with NaNs where there is no data, just as I want it! 
BUT, I still cannot index because `data.index` is `Index([u'amy', u'ben', u'clara', u'daisy'], dtype='object')` so I can only index in one direction again.

How can I achieve this 2D matrix?

Thank you.

EDIT1:

If I unstack once the result is:

```
>>> data2.ix[:,:]
         rating            
artist  houston  psy  swift
user                       
amy           4  3.0      4
ben         NaN  2.0      5
clara         4  3.5    NaN
daisy         3  NaN      5
```

Then I want to index the Psy column like: `data2.ix[:,'psy']`
But I get `KeyError: 'psy'`
`data2.ix[:,:]` works though.

```
>>> data2.ix[:,['psy']]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [amy, ben, clara, daisy]
```

Edit2:
Expected output

```
>>> data2.ix[:,1]
user
amy      3.0
ben      2.0
clara    3.5
daisy    NaN
Name: (rating, psy), dtype: float64
```

But I want to use 'psy' instead of 1.

Edit3: csv

```
amy swift   4
amy psy 3
amy houston 4
ben swift   5
ben psy 2
clara   psy 3.5
clara   houston 4
daisy   swift   5
daisy   houston 3
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html)?

Comment: Can you mock up an example of your expected output? You might also want to try `data.unstack().as_matrix()`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `pivot_table` the result I got was the same as with my method.

`as_matrix()` seems to be exactly what I want! I'll mess around with it now. Although it seems I lose the ability to index by 'string'.

Comment: can you include a csv we can read in? or the output of `.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have unstacked, the data frame has an extra level of hierarchy for `rating`. This appears to work as you want it to:

```
import pandas
raw = {'rating': {('amy', 'houston'): 4.0,
  ('amy', 'psy'): 3.0,
  ('amy', 'swift'): 4.0,
  ('ben', 'psy'): 2.0,
  ('ben', 'swift'): 5.0,
  ('clara', 'houston'): 4.0,
  ('clara', 'psy'): 3.5,
  ('daisy', 'houston'): 3.0,
  ('daisy', 'swift'): 5.0}}
data = pandas.DataFrame(raw)
data2 = data.unstack()

data2.rating.ix[:, 'psy']

=>

amy      3.0
ben      2.0
clara    3.5
daisy    NaN
Name: psy, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I was wondering what the 'rating' object meant and didn't know that it's accessible like that.

Comment: No problem. You can actually always access columns like that (without indexing and using strings), so `data2.rating.psy` would give the same result.